# What is exactly the purpose of the "vocabulary" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[vocabulary](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is simply described as, "for questions about a specific word."

What is exactly its purpose?
If I take its description as it is, I would use it in every question where I am asking about a word, and in that case it doesn't seem much helpful. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper use seems to me to be as a designation for a *body* of words, not for members of a body.

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/how-to-memorize-5500-english-words-within-the-shortest-time), for instance, strikes me as an appropriate use:

> **How to memorize 5500 English words within the shortest time?**
>   I am considering to appear for GRE. For this purpose, I have bought a vocabulary book containing 5500 words.
>   It must be mentioned that I work 12 hours per day and thus I have limited free time.
>   My questions are:
>
> > - What major factors apply rapid study?
> > - Is learning by vocabulary an affective technique to prepare specifically for GRE test?
> >
> >   - If so, how many days would be a realistic target?
> >   - If not, what learning techniques let me prepare myself within the shortest possible period of time?

Another appropriate use of the tag was on the question [**Card game vocabulary**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324/card-game-vocabulary) (which was closed as Off Topic). The other questions with this tag, however, are common-or-garden-variety word requests, and should be retagged.

Comment: I agree. The tag description has apparently been changed since OP cited the earlier (and inappropriate) *"for questions about a specific word."*